# What exactly do we do in non-rigid registration?

Tags: image-registration, point-cloud

I found many readings on `Non rigid registration`, also saw some videos but didn't find a clear explanation anywhere.

What I understood is the following

**Rigid Registration:** It is the alignment of two point clouds without changing the shape (ie only by rotation and translation). ICP algorithm is used. The closest point in the other point cloud is assumed to be the corresponding point.

- Correspondence detection is not necessary for all the points.
- All the points are applied the same transformation.
- Iterative

**Non-rigid registration:** In this case, the shape of the point cloud might change. But what exactly are we doing? Are we finding the corresponding points using `Spin Images`, and then applying separate transformations (translations in this case) for every corresponding point?

- Correspondence detection has to be done for all the points.
- All the points are applied their separate transformations (might be same).
- Not iterative: Just apply a translation

**Piecewise rigid registration:** We divide the non-rigid point cloud into many rigid parts and then apply separate rigid transformations per part. This lies between rigid and non-rigid registration.

- Correspondence detection is done for only some of the points.
- Same transformation is applied to those points in a particular rigid part, but different parts might have different transformations.
- Iterative

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Also, is there any role of `SIFT` in correspondence detection. I've seen some links for SIFT in 3D.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this survey paper very useful:
http://ralph.cs.cf.ac.uk/papers/Geometry/Registration.pdf

It gives a categorized overview of the field. I think section 3 and 4 are the most relevant ones for you.

Answer (score 0):

Registration is the recovery of a spatial transform that applies one data set (can be a point cloud) onto another. The spatial transform can include rigid motion (no deformation) and deformation; in the case of piecewise rigid deformation, the system is a mechanism, i.e. a number of rigid parts having different motions.

Whatever the case, the transformations are described by a number of degrees of freedom (translation, rotations, shrinking, locations of control points...) and associated parameters. The registration process uses information from the original and transformed data sets to estimate the parameters associated to these DOF.

For example, when registering appoint cloud onto another with known correspondences, every point pair gives a transformation equation, which can be used to resolve one DOF. Usually there a more equations than unknown parameters, and (robust) fitting techniques are used, such as RANSAC.